# how to assign hex value to a variable in objective c

Tags: objective-c, hex

This is a very newb question...

```
??? hexvalue = 0xFFFFFF;
```

What do I replace `???` with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0xFFFFFF` is identical to saying `16777215`, what type would you put for `16777215`?

They're just numbers, so int32_t, NSInteger, NSUInteger, long, etc are all valid.